# Фильтрация объектов из массива и обрезка ссылки

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть некий массив и простенькая функция по выводу данных из него:

```js
var arr=[
    ['1','Name 01','/logo01.png','link01.html'],
    ['2','Name 02','/logo02.png','link02.html'],
    ['3','Name key 03','/logo03.png','link03.html'],
    ['4','Name 04','/logo04.png','link04.html'],
    ['5','Name 05','/logo05.png ~ /image.jpg','link05.html'],
    ['6','Name yek 06','/logo06.png','link06.html'],
]

var text = '';
var i;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  text += "<a href='"  + arr[i][3] +  "'>" + arr[i][1] + "</a>(" + arr[i][2] + ")<br>";
}
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

**Вопросы:**

1. Как правильно отфильтровать массив, убрав из него объекты, в которых содержатся "key" и "yek".
2. Как оставить одну ссылку на изображение в этом случае `/logo05.png ~ /image.jpg`? То, есть, очистить все лишнее после `/logoХХ.png`?

В конечном итоге, результат должен быть таким:

```
<div id="test">
    <a href="link01.html">Name 01</a>(/logo01.png)<br>
    <a href="link02.html">Name 02</a>(/logo02.png)<br>
    <a href="link04.html">Name 04</a>(/logo04.png)<br>
    <a href="link05.html">Name 05</a>(/logo05.png)<br>
</div>
```

Спасибо за любое решение или банальную ссылку на схожие примеры.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var arr = [
  ['1','Name 01','/logo01.png','link01.html'],
  ['2','Name 02','/logo02.png','link02.html'],
  ['3','Name key 03','/logo03.png','link03.html'],
  ['4','Name 04','/logo04.png','link04.html'],
  ['5','Name 05','/logo05.png ~ /image.jpg','link05.html'],
  ['6','Name yek 06','/logo06.png','link06.html'],
];

var exclusions = [ "key", "yek" ];

var arr1 = arr.filter(item => {
  for (var j = 0; j < exclusions.length; j++) {
    if (item[1].indexOf(exclusions[j]) != -1)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
});

var text = '';
var i;
for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  text += "<a href='"  + arr1[i][3] +  "'>" + arr1[i][1] + "</a>(" + arr1[i][2].split("~")[0].trim() + ")<br>";
}
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я примерно через `.indexOf` и видел момент сравнения в данном примере. А можно ли упростить запись, если слов будет много? То есть, задать набор слов в другом массиве и затем сравнить все совпадения с основным массивом?

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev Добавил массив `exclusions`.